# Passing arguments to python unittest

Tags: python

I have a functional test 'y1.py' which I am trying to pass arguments to, from within a python/django function. Inside the calling function I have:

```
import unittest, sys
import ft1.y1
ft1.y1.testVars = [1, 2, 3, "foo"]
unittest.main(module=ft1.y1, argv=sys.argv[:1], exit=False)
```

based on h.ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812132/how-to-pass-variables-using-unittest-suite

y1.py:

```
   from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re    

class Y1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
         print('tvars' +self.testVars )

     ....................


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I'm getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\envs\r1\driver1\ft1\y1.py", line 17, in setUp
    print('tvars '+ y1.testVars )
AttributeError: type object 'y1' has no attribute 'testVars'    

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.330s    

FAILED (errors=1)
[02/Feb/2014 23:59:42] "GET /runtest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

As suggested I changed the line to :

```
print('tvars' + sys.module[__name__].testVars )
```

I'm getting:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_y1 (ft1.y1.y1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\envs\r1\driver1\ft1\y1.py", line 17, in setUp
    print('tvars' + sys.module[__name__].testVars )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module'    

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.981s    

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make a reference to the module rather than the class (your `testVars` are on the **module** level) you should probably use `sys.modules[__name__].testVars` which makes:

```
print('tvars' +self.testVars )
```

Become:

```
print('tvars' + sys.modules[__name__].testVars )
```

Comment: you perhaps really mean `sys.modules`?  pluralized?

Comment: Thanks to both of you , I used print('tvars ' + str(sys.modules[__name__].testVars )) and it worked